# Laravel extend TestResponse class

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, phpunit

I'm trying to add a custom assertion to the [`TestReponse`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.html) class so I can make something like this:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/foo/bar');

$response->myCustomAssertion();
```

I tried creating an `App\TestResponse` class that extends the original one and then binding it in the `App\Provider\AppServiceProvider` class.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse', function ($app) {
        return new App\TestResponse();
    });
}
```

But `$response->json()` is still returning the original one and not my own implementation.

How can I extend the `TestResponse` class?

Comment: it is 'macroable' you dont have to extend it to add methods .. you can add methods at run time via a static `macro` call on that class

Comment: @lagbox can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `TestResponse` class uses the `Macroable` trait so you can add macro functions at runtime.

```
TestResponse::macro('nameOfFunction', function (...) {
    ...
});
```

You can add this to a Service Provider's `boot` method or somewhere before you need to make the call to that macro'ed method.

Answer (score 16):

If you want a little more fine-grained control, you can also extend the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse`, as you have done, and then override the `createTestResponse` method in your `TestCase` class to return an instance of your custom response class:

```php
// Laravel 8 and above
protected function createTestResponse($response)
{
    return tap(App\TestResponse::fromBaseResponse($response), function ($response) {
        $response->withExceptions(
            $this->app->bound(LoggedExceptionCollection::class)
                ? $this->app->make(LoggedExceptionCollection::class)
                : new LoggedExceptionCollection
        );
    });
}

// Before Laravel 8
protected function createTestResponse($response)
{
    return App\TestResponse::fromBaseResponse($response);
}
```

From [`Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php).