# laravel testing how to remove some failed output?

Tags: laravel

I am testing some apis with laravel 8.

When a test is OK, I see this result :

[image]

It is clear, concise. Perfect !

When a test is KO, I  would like to have an equivalent result, without the detail of the problem :

[image]

I tried a lot of options (--quiet, -v -vv -vvv) without success. Is it possible to obtain this kind of result ?

Answer (score 0):

Add  `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` on top your testmethods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am looking for something more generalist which can work on all the methods. And not only on a specific method.

Comment: @Dom alright! Maybe you have to override the TestResponse Class. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382236/14807111